# inter-process communication with data sending in c

Tags: c, posix

I am in a scenario where I have to write a program that creates two processes. The father process
opens a text file for reading. It is assumed that the file is composed of words formed of
alphabetic characters separated by spaces. The child process enters a word on the keyboard. The
father process looks for the word in the file, and passes to the child the value 1 if the word is in
the file, and 0 otherwise. The son displays the result.

Here I think used the tubes for communication between these processes.
However, this communication seems to me difficult.
Does this ordering:
process father-process son-process father-process son is possible?

Comment: Yes, pipes work in both directions, so the parent can wait for the child, and then the child can wait for the parent.

Comment: What can we then do for the sending of data.
I can just send on a meaning through the streams.
Now this case seems to me very heavy. Can you explain to me with an illustration (no code) or a tutorial on this specific case

Comment: Although a single pipe can be used in both directions, it is less troublesome and more common to use two, one for each direction.  As for data transfer, I would suggest using `fdopen()` to wrap each pipe end in a stream.  Then use standard stream I/O -- `printf`, `puts`, `putchar`, `fgets`, `getchar`, maybe even `scanf`.

Comment: Read [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html), [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). Read a good POSIX programming book (perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/)...)

Comment: So I transmit the data by calling the function sleep to wait for the execution of the son, then sleep to wait for the execution of the father and so on . So I pass the data by calling the sleep function to wait for the execution of the child, then sleep to wait for the father's execution, and so on. Same advice for two tubes if possible.

Comment: You don't [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) but [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), and `poll` can multiplex and wait on *several* file descriptors. You probably want some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around `poll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching a simple pipe program for basic understanding. One can modify according to her needs.

```
/* simple_pipe.c

   Simple demonstration of the use of a pipe to communicate
   between a parent and a child process.

   Usage: simple_pipe "string"

   The program creates a pipe, and then calls fork() to create a child process.
   After the fork(), the parent writes the string given on the command line
   to the pipe, and the child uses a loop to read data from the pipe and
   print it on standard output.
*/

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"

#define BUF_SIZE 10

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pfd[2];                             /* Pipe file descriptors */
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    ssize_t numRead;

    if (argc != 2 || strcmp(argv[1], "--help") == 0)
        usageErr("%s string\n", argv[0]);

    if (pipe(pfd) == -1)                    /* Create the pipe */
        errExit("pipe");

    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        errExit("fork");

    case 0:             /* Child  - reads from pipe */
        if (close(pfd[1]) == -1)            /* Write end is unused */
            errExit("close - child");

        for (;;) {              /* Read data from pipe, echo on stdout */
            numRead = read(pfd[0], buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (numRead == -1)
                errExit("read");
            if (numRead == 0)
                break;                      /* End-of-file */
            if (write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, numRead) != numRead)
                fatal("child - partial/failed write");
        }

        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
        if (close(pfd[0]) == -1)
            errExit("close");
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    default:            /* Parent - writes to pipe */
        if (close(pfd[0]) == -1)            /* Read end is unused */
            errExit("close - parent");

        if (write(pfd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) != strlen(argv[1]))
            fatal("parent - partial/failed write");

        if (close(pfd[1]) == -1)            /* Child will see EOF */
            errExit("close");
        wait(NULL);                         /* Wait for child to finish */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Have a look on more examples here on Chapter-44 [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/all_files_by_chapter.html).
Keep this book on your table or e-book on you computer, it's a bible for Linux programming.